# What would be the best way to implement Magic Link logins in WordPress?

Tags: login, rest-api, api, wp-remote-request, remote-login

On the internet I saw several plugins/services offering a kind of a 'magic login' link functionality. This allows users to sign in without a password but with a magic link.

That made me wondering: If I want to implement this myself, how would I do this?

I do not necessarily need to send emails, but just the process of getting a link/specific endpoint that signs a user in.

Edit: after a little bit more digging I found the [`wp_signon()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) function, which I think could be used for this.

It would be great if you could show me how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I would review the source code of some of the plugins you found and adapt your findings to your needs. It should give you a solid starting point, but I think there are too many considerations in implementing to solve in a simple SO code snippet